# Bootstrapping a Backbone application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, requirejs, amd

I have seen a couple of ways on how to do this, but I can never figure out which is the 'correct' way.

[Jeffrey Way from NetTuts+](https://tutsplus.com/course/build-your-own-slide-engine/)  and [Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/#exercise-building-a-modular-backbone-app-with-amd-requirejs) instantiate a 'main' application view in order to kick off their applications.

```
require(['views/app'], function(AppView) {
  new AppView();
});
```

[Ryan Bates from Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1) starts his application by instantiating a router which then handles subsequent requests:

```
window.App =
    Models: {}
    Collections: {}
    Views: {}
    Routers: {}

    init: ->
        new App.Router()
        Backbone.history.start()
    }
}

$(document).ready ->
    App.init()
```

Is there an important difference between these two ways of bootstrapping an application?

I quite like how Ryan Bates creates an `App` object to which he attaches all his models, views, ... He uses CoffeeScript though, I'm not sure if this makes any difference in how this object gets handled. I tried this and I couldn't get it to work with RequireJS:

```
require(['jquery', 'backbone', 'router'], function ($, Backbone, Router) {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Aggregator: _.extend({}, Backbone.Events),
        Hook: $('#application'),
        Router: Router,

        init: function() {
            new App.Router();
            Backbone.history.start();
        }
    }
    $(document)ready(function() {
        App.init();
    });
});
```

I then have a simple router which creates a loginView when the index route gets hit:

```
define(['backbone', 'loginView'], function(Backbone, LoginView) {
  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
      '': 'index'
    },

    index: function() {
      var loginView = new LoginView();
    }  

  });

  return Router;
});
```

And my loginView:

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
  var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

  });



  return LoginView;
});
```

To follow Ryan Bates' way of working, I wanted to do something like:

```
App.Views.LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({});
```

but I'm not quite sure how this differs from what he does in coffeescript:

```
class App.Views.LoginView extends Backbone.View
```

When I log 'App' to the console in my LoginView's `initialize` method, I get the object from my main.js file, however, when I try to attach something to the App.Views object, it says App.Views is undefined. Must be doing something wrong here?

Comment: I don't think the require.js and Rails approaches are compatible. Require.js wants to handle things its way with dependencies explicitly listed in the `define` calls, this mostly negates the need for `window.App`. The Rails way is to throw everything in one big pile via the asset pipeline so a global `window.App` is necessary to avoid a big mess. AFAIK, you'd have to pass `window.App` to the `define` functions just like you have to pass them `Backbone`. I'm not a require.js guy though so I could be missing something obvious.

Comment: Thank you. I am still learning to use Require.js so what you're saying might be correct. I hope someone will be able to shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Don't trust me too far though, hopefully some require.js people will be along to clarify things. BTW, `App.Views.LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({});` and `class App.Views.LoginView extends Backbone.View` are functionally equivalent.

Comment: FWIW, here's my opinions / approach: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/06/3-stages-of-a-backbone-applications-startup/

Comment: @muistooshort You're absolutely right. Using RequireJs obviates the need for globals. Everything is encapsulated in its own module. If RequireJS behaves like a service locator and preserves state of the modules between calls (assuming modules indeed encapsulate an object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're creating:

```
App.Views.LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({});
```

It's quite different from:

```
class App.Views.LoginView extends Backbone.View
```

You can check the coffeescript by converting it from [coffee to js](http://js2coffee.org/):

```
var __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
__extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

App.Views.LoginView = (function(_super) {

  __extends(LoginView, _super);

  function LoginView() {
    return LoginView.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }

return LoginView;

})(Backbone.View);
```

I'd recommend checking out the repo for [todomvc's backbone-require setup](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/dependency-examples/backbone_require).

I have a coffeescript [todo setup](https://github.com/jmparsons/play-scala-backbone-todo) based loosely on both with a global app object not attached to the window, but using sub objects to hold collections, models, views etc.