# How to pass a route parameter to the main View?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I use a very simple router to route all page requests.  I start my app by instantiating BVApp.

Recently, I added in routing and I only use the first parameter `page1`.  How can I pass this parameter to my BVApp code.

I know that I probably should not pass it in via the constructor as only certain parameters are allowed by Backbone which uses `_.pick`.  See [here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-152)

Can I call it as a method on BVApp perhaps?

I looked at this [SO post for ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053466/bootstrapping-a-backbone-application) after a [Googled search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Backbone%20how%20to%20start%20an%20application) pulled up nothing obvious.

Perhaps my entry point into my application should not be a Backbone View at all?

```
// BRMain
var BRMain = Backbone.Router.extend({
    Name: 'BRMain',
    routes: {
        "*page1(/:supertag)(/:tag)": "main"
    }
});

var router = new BRMain();

// matches
//   domain.com
//   domain.com#page1
//   domain.com#page1/supertag
//   domain.com#page1/supertag/tag
router.on('route:main', function (page1, supertag, tag) {
    var App = $A.Mod.add(new BVApp());
});

Backbone.history.start();

// BVApp
var BVApp = Backbone.View.extend({
    Name: 'BVApp',
    el: window,
    initialize: function () {
        var public_page = $A.Reg.get('pub_req');
        var token = Storage.getToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `initialize` function takes an optional `options` object, which is the same object you pass to your view's constructor.

```
router.on('route:main', function(page1, supertag, tag) {
    // pass any arguments inside the object here
    var App = $A.Mod.add(new BVApp({
        page: page1
    }));
});

var BVApp = Backbone.View.extend({
    Name: 'BVApp',
    el: window,
    initialize: function(options) {
        options = options || {};

        // then you can use them here
        this.page = options.page;
    }

});
```

This is not well explained inside Backbone's documentation, but it is a common pattern of all their objects. For example, here's a sample of [Backbone's View source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-149).

```
var View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('view');
    _.extend(this, _.pick(options, viewOptions));
    this._ensureElement();

    // lastly, they call initialize passing all arguments along
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

In fact, any arguments passed to a constructor in Backbone is passed along to the `initialize` function.